# ajax error handler when internet connection lost

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, error-handling

I've some ajax calls in which I would like to add handler in case of an error. I found the "error" handler but that doesn't work i.e. **when internet connection is lost**. Is there a second handler for these cases?

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "dosomethink.php",
      success: function (data) {
        $('#abc').html(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

Comment: And how exactly did you troubleshoot a lost internet connection?

Comment: @Thomas1703 You can use timeout for connection lost issue.

Comment: Why not use navigator.onLine or an XHR request?

Comment: Plz look at this Bounty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058764/determine-if-ajax-call-failed-due-to-insecure-response-or-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

what if you using timeout and the error method

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET',url: '/controller/action',timeout: 15000,success: function(data) {},error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,errorThrown) {}});
```