# How can access the error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE from the returned promise object

Tags: angularjs, http, jsonp

I am receiving the following error when I make a GET request using jsonp in angularjs. Below is a code snippet being used :

```
        var url = 'https://ap-codereview.us.oracle.com/api/review-requests/' + 
                getCodereviewId(vm.details.codereview_url) + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http.jsonp(url).then(codereviewSuccessFn, codereviewErrorFn);

        function codereviewSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.show = true;
            vm.codereviewDetails = data.data.review_request;
        }

        function codereviewErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.show = false;
            Snackbar.error(
                "Make sure you have accepted the security certificate warning when logging into codereview from chrome."+
                "Manually accept this warning."
                    + data.statusText + " : " + data.status);
                //Need logic here to differentiate above error from 404 NOT FOUND
                Snackbar.error(vm.details.codereview_url + " does not exist");
        }
```

The response in the developer console on chrome shows me net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

```
GET https://ap-codereview.us.oracle.com/api/review-requests/29113?callback=angular.callbacks._0 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

I know why this error is happening, which is not my concern, however I need to configure the error message being displayed in the snackbar based on the error type, which is `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. I need to diffrentiate between the ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE and 404 NOT FOUND messages in general.

My question is how can I access the ERROR type from the returned promise object ? I tried browsing through the object and only found a 404/error in the Status/StatusText.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know you can't get the actual 'net::' error, but `status` had a value of '0' when I get a 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error. But this maybe browser specific. In some cases it is also possible that `status` is empty.

Comment: The status, headers and config elements are all undefined in both ERR_SECURE_RESPONSE and 404 NOT FOUND.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if ajax call failed due to insecure response or connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058764/determine-if-ajax-call-failed-due-to-insecure-response-or-connection-refused)