# How to capture "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" in Angular Application to handle SSL certificate issue?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, developer-tools, browser-console

I need to capture "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"  in Angular Application to handle SSL certificate issue so that I can guide user to downloading install SSL certificate from a particular location but I am not able to find a way to get programmatically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv6gT.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if ajax call failed due to insecure response or connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058764/determine-if-ajax-call-failed-due-to-insecure-response-or-connection-refused)

Comment: Thanks  mate, it helped me somehow to understand  the problem